# Upgraded from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7, and I get this error

Tags: drupal

I attempted to upgrade my D6 installation to D7, but when I hit my home page now, I get this string of errors:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in drupal_theme_initialize() (line 100 of /public_html/includes/theme.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in _drupal_theme_initialize() (line 146 of /public_html/includes/theme.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in _theme_load_registry() (line 335 of /public_html/includes/theme.inc).
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in template_preprocess_maintenance_page() (line 2733 of /public_html/includes/theme.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in template_preprocess_maintenance_page() (line 2733 of /public_html/includes/theme.inc).
Warning: array_keys() [function.array-keys]: The first argument should be an array in template_preprocess_maintenance_page() (line 2736 of /public_html/includes/theme.inc).
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in template_preprocess_maintenance_page() (line 2736 of /public_html/includes/theme.inc).
```

Does anyone know how I fix this?!

Worse yet, I can't access my /user (login) page to get to my admin panel. Clearing my cache via PHPMyAdmin doesn't work either.

HELP :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it may be your theme that is an issue. It may not be compatible with D7. To test this enable the base garland theme and make it your default.

WARNING - WE ARE GOING TO MANUALLY EDIT THE DATBASE. MAKE A BACKUP OF YOUR DATABASE BEFORE ATTEMPTING THIS!!!

First make sure the garland theme is enabled by executing this query in phpmyadmin

```
UPDATE system SET status=1 WHERE name LIKE '%garland';
```

Then set it as your default theme and truncate the cache tables by running these queries

```
UPDATE variable SET value='s:7:"garland"' WHERE name = 'theme_default';
TRUNCATE cache;
TRUNCATE cache_bootstrap;
TRUNCATE cache_block;
```

If your site is now accessible, you can focus on fixing your theme. If it isn't a custom theme, check the theme's project page and see if there is an update for D7.

If you are still having problems, post back and we can dig deeper.

I would make a couple of recommendations for the future as well.

Start by getting a local install of your site for testing. You can run WAMP (http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or MAMP (http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) if you are on a Mac. Then you can upgrade locally and catch these problems before they hit your live site.

Second, always make a backup of your site files and database before upgrading. Rolling back will only take a few minutes and you will be very happy to have that backup when (not if) something goes wrong.

Comment: Did all of the above. I changed the theme to 'Bartik', and that fixed the error messages (yay!), however the /user & ?q=user page is still "not found".

Comment: Try also truncating cache_content and cache_menu tables as well.

Comment: Cleared those as well; still "not found" :/

Comment: Are you able to access any other pages on your site? Can you get to /user/login? Do you have ssh access to the server hosting your site?

Comment: When I attempt to access other pages it says the site is in maintenance mode (because it is). But /user/login "can't be found" either.

Comment: Hmm - it sounds like there might have been a problem with the upgrade. Try running update.php to see if you can get it to finish and clean up after itself.

To do this without logging in, edit your settings.php file and change update_free_access to TRUE, then go to http://www.yoursite.com/update.php and walk through the process. Change the setting back to FALSE after you finish because it is a security issue.

Comment: So when I re-run the update.php, It throws me an, "Unrecoverable error". And that error is this: An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. Path: /update.php?op=selection&token=oLo0AbPjyQk-kA0AwkXzXgtRENhxwNpjpe67Z1T9aQg&id=7&op=do StatusText: OK ResponseText: Fatal error: Call to undefined function _update_7000_field_read_fields() in public_html/modules/image/image.install on line 366

Comment: Update: So I removed all of the themes and attempted to run update.php again. I stopped getting all of the sql errors (as I fixed some of the table errors manually), and now the ONLY error I get is this: The update process was aborted prematurely while running update #7004 in taxonomy.module. All errors have been logged. You may need to check the watchdog database table manually.

Comment: Can you look in the watchdog table and post the error messages here?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it will take some manual work to get your database back in order. Getting stuck in the middle of an upgrade is painful. If you have a backup of code and db, I'd roll back and try to get it working in a different environment. If you don't have backups, the only way forward is to manually fix things and update the db little by little until everything is working again.